# (1/1) ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting an exceptional error :

> HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property 'id' of
> non-object'

I dont know whats wrong with my code, i suspect the `->user()->id` .

Any help will be appreciated.

```
if (app_config('sender_id_verification') == '1') {
    $all_sender_id = SenderIdManage::where('status', 'unblock')->get();
    $all_ids = [];

    foreach ($all_sender_id as $sid) {
        $client_array = json_decode($sid->cl_id);

        if (isset($client_array) && is_array($client_array) && in_array('0', $client_array)) {
            array_push($all_ids, $sid->sender_id);

        } elseif (isset($client_array) && is_array($client_array) && in_array(Auth::guard('client')->user()->id, $client_array)) {
            array_push($all_ids, $sid->sender_id);
        }
    }
    $sender_ids = array_unique($all_ids);
}
```

Comment: Its like the error says, you're trying to get the ID of a non object. You say that you think the problem is the ->user()->id but i cant find it in your code. Can you provide more of the code?

Comment: `Auth::guard('client')->user()->id` it's likely there's no user authenticated on the `client` guard

Comment: @Collin check line 8

Comment: @apokryfos is right, you have to check if the user is authenticated in order to get the ID.

Comment: @apokryfos It was working well before, this issue started showing just a few hours ago.

Comment: By working you mean you could successfully log in using the `client` guard and get the user and now you can't anymore? Can you share some more detail on how the client guard is configured?